# use generic entityConverter (proposed by BalusC) for selectonemenu if primefaces

Tags: jsf, generics, primefaces, converters, selectonemenu

I want to use [this generic converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273528/157762) in all `<p:selectOneMenu />` but it doesn't show data and I have no exceptions.

I don't know the problem

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="articles-type" style="margin-right:20px;"
                 converter="entityConverter"
                 value="#{newsessionVentesMB.selectedTypeFiltre}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner Type" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{t.libelle}" itemValue="#{t}"
                   value="#{newsessionVentesMB.listTypes}" var="t" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

if your f:selectItems does not print any option, try to:

1. check #{newsessionVentesMB.listTypes}
2. remove converter
3. change from p:selectOneMenu to h:selectOneMenu

only for debug purpose.

without any info on how newsessionVentesMB.listTypes is implemented this is the best i con do...

Comment: Proceed as Michele Mariotti sais and make sure that you're #{t.libelle} is not null for all the entries of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting **noSelectionOption="true"** on the empty selectItem like this:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner Type" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

I hope this helps.